# Buck converter welding machine

Tags: transistors

Can I use a high power (2-6 kw power supply) synchronous buck converter ( at least 85% efficiency)  to work as a welding machine that outputs around 10 -20 VDC and 100 -300 amps? If I can, what is the best kind of transistor for this application? ( igbt or a mosfet)

Comment: why not just buy a welding machine? also what's the spec for the input, e.g. voltage, frequency?

Comment: A really, really big one.

Comment: Arc welding machine needs about 60V to light up the arc and then falls to 10-20V. Actually it is best to maintain constant current, not constant voltage. When voltage drops less than a couple of volts the current should be reduced, so the electrode will not stick to the welded details in case of a not trained operator. Better buy a working inverter welder. Price for 160-200A has fallen to about $150.

Comment: Probably IGBT. But you should sure as hell not build a non-isolated **buck converter** that operates from the mains. **You'll kill someone**.

Comment: IGBT for sure, but as Todor said, you need to strike the arc somehow. A common method is to have a high secondary voltage with low duty cycle which gives you high voltage in DCM and low voltage but high current in CCM. External strike mechanisms exists too.